# Is there a way to pass service/containers in child process?

Tags: php, symfony, asynchronous

I am testing spatie's async project. I created a task as such.

```
use Spatie\Async\Task;

class ServiceTask extends Task
{
    protected $accountService;
    protected $serviceFactory;

    public function __construct(ServiceFactory $serviceFactory)
    {
        $this->serviceFactory = $serviceFactory;
    }
    public function configure()
    {
        $this->accountService = $this->serviceFactory->getAccountService();
    }

    public function run()
    {
        //accounting tasks
    }
}
```

And for the pool:

```
$pool = Pool::create();

foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
    $pool->add(new ServiceTask($serviceFactory))
        // handlers
    ;
}

$pool->wait();
```

When I run the above code, I simply get

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

I know that we cannot simply serialize  a closure, I tried the same code above with a simple plain Data Transfer Object, it worked fine. But when passing a service, or a container class from symfony I get above error. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: I recommend reading the blog-post regarding spatie's async to get a better understanding about its intended use. It may be possible to call a function that setups everything as you need it (the full system) and then it could be possible and it may match your "passing" semantics - but your mileage may vary.

Comment: You may be able to look into using this library https://github.com/opis/closure

Comment: Did one of the answers help you? Please consider to accept an answer. I saw you've asked 12 questions so far, but never accepted an answer. Some of the answers on your questions didn't receive any votes or comments.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no

Longer answer: Spatie Async serializes task before adding it to the pool, so you might need an alternative solution.

### Why Async needs a serialized task

See relevant code to understand what's going on:
[Pool::add](https://github.com/spatie/async/blob/d371b76ff876530c4906596490fd977720477e48/src/Pool.php#L140) > [ParentRuntime::createProcess](https://github.com/spatie/async/blob/d371b76ff876530c4906596490fd977720477e48/src/Runtime/ParentRuntime.php#L57) > [ParentRuntime::encodeTask](https://github.com/spatie/async/blob/d371b76ff876530c4906596490fd977720477e48/src/Runtime/ParentRuntime.php#L83).

For more discussion, see [this](https://github.com/spatie/async/issues/23) or  [this](https://github.com/spatie/async/issues/142) issue in `spatie/async`'s issue list.

### Alternative: Symfony Messenger

There are many alternatives to this problem. Since you're using Symfony, you might be interested in [Symfony Messenger](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html) to send messages to a handler. Those handlers can use dependency injection:

```
class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    public function index(MessageBusInterface $bus)
    {
        $bus->dispatch(new ServiceTask('Look! I created a message!'));
    }
}

class ServiceTaskHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    protected $accountService;
    protected $serviceFactory;

    public function __construct(ServiceFactory $serviceFactory)
    {
        $this->serviceFactory = $serviceFactory;
        $this->accountService = $this->serviceFactory->getAccountService();
    }

    public function __invoke(ServiceTask $task)
    {
         $this->accountService->handle($task);            
    }
}
```

Be aware that a Task (`ServiceTask` in this example) should (like `spatie/async`'s task) be serializable as well. So you might send an ID as a message, and look up that ID in your `MessageHandler`

Answer (score 1):

Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed is an error that is formed when passing a cued event as an argument. Likely the issue has to do with creating the object in a factory then passing it as part of the constructor.